# Getting Potentially dangerous Request.Path (?) intermittently

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc app that has a catch all route setup that occasionally throws a dangerous request path exception on '?'.

I have the route setup like

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "ImageResponse", // Route name
  "{*_*}", // Just cute
  new { controller = "ImageResponse", action = "RenderImage" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I get exceptions on paths saying that '?' was a dangerous request, but I can't reproduce it (copy and paste it straight out of event logs). This seems to happen when I put a bit of load on the machine.

For example, I found something like this in my event logs (everything left of the .jpg has been change to protect the innocent, although there are three dirs and a file name).

`/an/example/path/image.jpg?Size=Thumb`

Has anyone run into this issue before? It seems like something isn't detecting my filename there.

Comment: Are you using SquishIt by any chance?

Comment: I have no idea what that is, so I doubt it :)

Comment: are you're certain there's no special characters in the actual path? you're not URL encoding the ? are you? and you have .jpg mime type setup correctly?

Comment: and shouldn't your catch all be `{*url}` rather than `{*_*}`?

Comment: @timothyclifford - Hmm, looks like the url encoding might be the issue! I can reproduce the issue when doing that, and checking the logs after that has happened shows the '?' "helpfully" unencoded. Do you want to put that into an answer?

Comment: @timothyclifford - The {*_*} is valid, basically everything after that first * is ignored, so it's just cute to do it that way.

Comment: @Khanzor ak ok, never seen `{*_*}` before :) hopefully the URL encoding is your issue! let me know if it turns out not to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you're certain there's no special characters in the actual path? you're not URL encoding the ? are you? this would cause it to be interpreted as part of the path rather than the beginning of the querystring.

More info/examples here:

[Why is using a URL containing a questionmark when redirecting gets a “potentially dangerous request”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547847/why-is-using-a-url-containing-a-questionmark-when-redirecting-gets-a-potentiall)

[A potentially dangerous Request.Path value.... contains only alphanumerics and an underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760137/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-contains-only-alphanumerics-and-a)